# Change variable outside of lambda in Scheme/Racket

Tags: lambda, syntax, macros, scheme, racket

The examples from the doc of Racket come with `lambda` always: https://docs.racket-lang.org/syntax/Defining_Simple_Macros.html

And my `define-syntax-parser` is like this:

```
(require syntax/parse/define)
(define-syntax-parser sp
  [_ #'(lambda (x) (set! x (add1 x)))]
)

(define a 0)
((sp) a)
(display a)
```

**Possible to do something like this (remove the `lambda`)?**

```
(require syntax/parse/define)
(define-syntax-parser sp
  [(f x) #'(set! x (add1 x))]
)

(define a 0)
(f a)
(display a)
```

The result is expected to be `1` but it's still `0`. And Scheme/Racket don't pass by reference(?!), so how to change those variables outside of lambda?

There's a related answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8998055/5581893
but it's about the deprecated `define-macro` (https://docs.racket-lang.org/compatibility/defmacro.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Macro can expand to anything, not just `lambda`.

```
#lang racket

(require syntax/parse/define)

(define-simple-macro (sp x:id) (set! x (add1 x)))

(define a 0)
(sp a)
(display a)
```

Or if you prefer to use `define-syntax-parser`:

```
#lang racket

(require syntax/parse/define)

(define-syntax-parser sp
  [(_ x:id) #'(set! x (add1 x))])

(define a 0)
(sp a)
(display a)
```

Comment: tks, saved me from that evil lambda :)

Comment: how is define-simple-macro different from define-syntax-rule? they look and do the same thing

Comment: They are essentially the same except that `define-simple-macro` supports `syntax-parse` features. Stuff like `{~datum ...}` or syntax class `:id`.